# Separate plugin configuration in Shopware subshops

Tags: php, plugins, shopware

I've got Shopware 5 plugin which adds some js code to the shop's template. There is `main shop_id = 1` and `subshop shop_id = 3`, and when I configure plugins there is separate configuration for each shop at `backend > configuration > plugin_manager > plugin > configuration`.

When I check it inside the db table `s_core_config_values` I see that there are two different configurations added for each `shop_id`.

In main pugin file I've got a subscriber method, where I'm getting my plugin configuration and then register some events, for example

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend' => 'doSthMethod',
    ];
}
```

But the problem is that there is always the main plugin configuration (the one for `shop_id = 1` even if I'm on my subshop. In my main plugin file

```
class Shopware_Plugins_Backend_Pluginname_Bootstrap extends Shopware_Components_Plugin_Bootstrap
```

there is `$config = $this->Config();` which always returns main shop configuration, so is there any way to get actual subshop configuration?

EDIT:

I've tried the solution from the 1st answer, but still, no matter what sub shop I'm making the request from, I'm getting my main shop returned when:

```
$this->container->get('models')->getRepository(\Shopware\Models\Shop\Shop::class)->getActiveDefault();
```

And with main shop returned I'm getting default store configuration from:

```
$this->container->get('shopware.plugin.cached_config_reader')->getByPluginName('PluginName', $shop);
```

When I call:

```
$this->container->get('models')->getRepository(\Shopware\Models\Shop\Shop::class)->getActiveShops();
```

Then I get list with all my shops, including sub shops, but I can't distinguish which sub shop the request came from.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `shopware.plugin.cached_config_reader` service to read the plugin configuration. You can find a good example in the [documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-configuration/#subshop-specific-plugin-configuration):

```
public function onPostDispatch(Enlight_Event_EventArgs $arguments)
{
    $shop = false;
    if ($this->container->initialized('shop')) {
        $shop = $this->container->get('shop');
    }

    if (!$shop) {
        $shop = $this->container->get('models')->getRepository(\Shopware\Models\Shop\Shop::class)->getActiveDefault();
    }

    $config = $this->container->get('shopware.plugin.cached_config_reader')->getByPluginName('PluginName', $shop);   

    [...]
}
```

Comment: I've tried this already, also added information about your solution in the main question.